# variable undefined when use window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Hi all I have variable defined in one js file. Now from this js file I am navigating page to one html file and I want to access that variable in that html file. I use window.location as:

```
window.location = "UI/demo/home.html";
```

But in home.html when I tried to access that variable which is declared in js file I got variable as undefined.  If I use changePage instead of window.location I got value of variable. Why is it so? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that html file loading the same js file? Javascript's state terminates when you navigate to a new page. If you want data preserved, you need to use a cookie, local storage, or pass around query variables.

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: @MarcB Yes that html file is loading the same js file.

Answer (score 1):

`changePage` changes the DOM of the page without reloading the loaded Javascript. `window.location` changes the page of the browser itself, reloading all content, including Javascript.

So while the two may seem to have the same effect, `changePage` is probably what you are looking for except in the cases where you want to deliberately reload the URL.

Also note that `changePage` has a `reloadPage` argument that basically does what `window.location` would without fancy animations, etc.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html